# tfjs: Adam learning rate decay

Tags: tensorflow.js, adam, learning-rate

How do I train a Tensorflow model using Adam optimizer that decays learning rate during the trining with Tensorflow.JS! (not python) I cannot find that the library provides an exponential decay scheduler nor `decay` parameter in `tf.train.adam(...)` constructor:

```js
  /**
     * Constructs a `tf.AdamOptimizer` that uses the Adam algorithm.
     * See [https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980)
     *
     * @param learningRate The learning rate to use for the Adam gradient
     * descent algorithm.
     * @param beta1 The exponential decay rate for the 1st moment estimates.
     * @param beta2 The exponential decay rate for the 2nd moment estimates.
     * @param epsilon A small constant for numerical stability.
     *
     * @doc {heading: 'Training', subheading: 'Optimizers', namespace: 'train'}
     */
    static adam(learningRate?: number, beta1?: number, beta2?: number, epsilon?: number): AdamOptimizer;
```

I can see tho that `adamax` optimizer has `decay` parameter but does it work the same way as `adam` does?

```js
 /**
     * Constructs a `tf.AdamaxOptimizer` that uses the Adamax algorithm.
     * See [https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980)
     *
     * @param learningRate The learning rate to use for the Adamax gradient
     * descent algorithm.
     * @param beta1 The exponential decay rate for the 1st moment estimates.
     * @param beta2 The exponential decay rate for the 2nd moment estimates.
     * @param epsilon A small constant for numerical stability.
     * @param decay The learning rate decay over each update.
     *
     * @doc {heading: 'Training', subheading: 'Optimizers', namespace: 'train'}
     */
    static adamax(learningRate?: number, beta1?: number, beta2?: number, epsilon?: number, decay?: number): AdamaxOptimizer;
```